# Python Dataframe get previous row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rows

```
              Open    High     Low   Close     Volume  Dividends  Stock Splits
Date                                                                                      
2020-07-31  324.60  325.33  320.05  325.22   85210800        0.0             0 
2020-08-03  327.01  328.31  326.42  327.48   53077900        0.0             0 
2020-08-04  326.55  328.74  326.55  328.74   41917900        0.0             0
```

How do I write the following in code:

> If current row `volume` is more than previous row `volume` then add new
> column titled `position` and subtract `close` - `open` of the current row ?

Comment: is it `df.shift()`?

Comment: You need the `.shift()` method.

Comment: Can you guys please elaborate in code. I'm still new to this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the most elegant but should work:

```
df['Position'] = np.nan
df.loc[df['Volume']>df.shift(periods=1)['Volume'],'Position'] = df.loc[df['Volume']>df.shift(periods=1)['Volume'],'Close']-df.loc[df['Volume']>df.shift(periods=1)['Volume'],'Open']
```

If you are ok with 0.00 for positions where the volume condition is not satisfied (rather than NaN), a simpler version will work:

```
df['Position'] = (df.shift(periods=1)['Volume'] <df['Volume']) *(df['Close']-df['Open'])
```

Comment: Anyway I can pass in another argument in there? Say close higher than open or something of that sort?

Answer (score 1):

If I read your requirements correctly, you can use the pattern:

```py
df.loc[{predicate}, {location}] = {expression}
```

So:

```py
df.loc[df.diff().Volume > 0, 'Position'] = df.Close - df.Open
```

Transforms:

```
     Open   Close      Volume
0  324.60  325.22  85210800.0
1  327.01  327.48  53077900.0
2  326.55  328.74  41917900.0
```

To:

```
     Open   Close      Volume  Position
0  324.60  325.22  85210800.0       NaN
1  327.01  327.48  53077900.0      0.47
2  326.55  328.74  41917900.0      2.19
```